# Any way to combine results from fulltext query

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search

I've got a fulltext MySQL query which works fairly well -- except for the fact that I end up with duplicate results in certain cases.  I've got several types of data that I'm trying to search: buildings, suites, assets, etc., each in its own table.  Each type of data also can have user-defined custom fields, the data for which is stored in a different table.  Here is my structure.

```
CREATE TABLE `buildings` (
 `bid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `status` enum('active','inactive') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `source` enum('feed','manual') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`bid`),
 FULLTEXT KEY `textsearch` (`name`)
)

CREATE TABLE `customfields` (
 `cfid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `datatype` enum('integer','date','smtext','lgtext','numeric','enum','linked') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `options` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
 `did` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Datasheet ID',
 PRIMARY KEY (`cfid`),
 KEY `did` (`did`)
)

CREATE TABLE `customfield_data` (
 `cfdid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `data_int` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `data_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `data_smtext` varchar(1000) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `data_lgtext` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
 `data_numeric` decimal(20,2) DEFAULT NULL,
 `linkid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'ID value of specific item',
 `cfid` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Custom field ID',
 PRIMARY KEY (`cfdid`),
 KEY `data_smtext` (`data_smtext`(333)),
 KEY `linkid` (`linkid`),
 KEY `cfid` (`cfid`),
 FULLTEXT KEY `textsearch` (`data_smtext`,`data_lgtext`)
)
```

So effectively, a building can have a customfield which stores its actual data in customfield_data.  A customfield is identified as a building-specific field by means of the did (dataset ID.)  The cfid field then links the customfield_data to the customfield and the data is linked to the specific building with the linkid field.

With that in mind, here's my fulltext query:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT (data_smtext + data_lgtext) AS data, linkid AS idvalue, did, MATCH(data_smtext, data_lgtext) AGAINST (?) AS relevance
  FROM customfield_data
  JOIN customfields ON customfield_data.cfid = customfields.cfid
  WHERE MATCH (data_smtext, data_lgtext) AGAINST (? IN BOOLEAN MODE)
  UNION
  SELECT name AS data, bid AS idvalue, 2 AS did, 3 * (MATCH(name) AGAINST (?)) AS relevance
  FROM buildings
  WHERE status = ? AND MATCH (name) AGAINST (? IN BOOLEAN MODE)
  UNION
  SELECT name AS data, bid AS idvalue, 2 AS did, 100 AS relevance
  FROM buildings
  WHERE bid LIKE ? AND status = ?
  UNION
  )
AS searchresults
WHERE relevance > 0
ORDER BY relevance DESC
```

As I mentioned earlier, this all works alright.  The problem that I'm running into is that if, for example, a building is *named* 123 North Ave Tower and it has an *address* (customfield) of 123 North Ave, then I get duplicate records -- one for the name and one for the address if I search for "123 North Ave".

They're both pointing to the same did (dataset ID) and linkid (building ID, in this case), so I know that I could solve my problem by cycling through the resulting array in PHP, looking for matches, and throwing out duplicates.  But that would hand me a performance hit and also would lower the effectiveness of the relevance scoring.  Ideally, I'd like to be able to have the query add the relevance of the address match to that of the name/ID match to give me a more accurate score.  Right now I'm multiplying the name match by 3x and leaving the customfield match at 1x in order to weight more accurate matches more heavily but adding the two would be the best option.

Thanks to anyone who can point me in the right direction!

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT ...`

Comment: Well, the problem is that they're in fact not distinct because the duplicate records will have different relevance scores.

Comment: plan 2, `GROUP BY` probably id

Comment: That does handle the duplication problem but unfortunately it eliminates the higher-ranking result.  I'd rather have the query combine the ranking value of the two results.

Answer (score 0):

I have no solution to this specific problem, but I solved it by installing and configuring Sphinx and letting that do my dirty work.

Answer (score 0):

The proposition to use group by is good. To get the right result, you need to sum the relevance in the select clause.

```
 sum ( match ( ... ) against (?)) as relevance
```